# What's the best API for automated forex trading?

Tags: api, cross-platform, trading, forex

I am interested in writing a small automatic trader for the forex market. I would like to chose my own tools (platform and programming language) and I just need to find a decent API to query the numbers and that accepts requests for trading actions. 
I guess the ideal would be some web service with a XML API, or similar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Check out the [InteractiveBrokers API](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1325) or the [Cunningham T4 API](http://sim.t4login.com/help/api/). Both are really good, although I'm not exactly sure T4 allows forex trading.

Answer (score 9):

MT4 is the industry standard. It allows simple interface through .dll files and has an extensive support base.

Comment: except it's a desktop client, that won't work if you want to run an online system I suppose

Comment: DLL files are compatible with .net so you can run them on a .net webserver.

Comment: There are a hundred ways to run it on/through a webserver. As I said, MT4 allows interface through dll files. That means you can interface with it through anything capable of interfacing with dll files (IIS, Apache, etc) . Additionally, you can use the Windows Desktop App API functions, (ex. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Since you can run MT4 on Linux through Wine, this means that you can run it through a Linux-based webserver too. There are lots of other ways. Look up MT4-web bridge.